# Firefox - mediaDevices.getUserMedia throws AbortError

Tags: firefox, webrtc, getusermedia

I get the following error in firefox (no problems in Chrome / Edge / Safari):

```
MediaStreamError { name: "AbortError", message: "Starting video failed", constraint: "", stack: "" }
```

Browser console only shows < unavailable > when this error is thrown.

I am using adapter-latest.js from webrtc.github.io and the code works perfectly well on other pages within my application but not in one particular page. Is there a possibility to find out, what interferes with getUserMedia? I allready tried commenting out all other libraries and includes.

My code is:

```
       var video = document.getElementById('recorder');
       video.onloadedmetadata = function(e) {
           $("#takePicture").show();

           if($("#customerImage").attr("src") == ""){
               $("#recorder").show();
           }
       };
       navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({ video: true})
           .then(stream => {
               video.srcObject = stream;
           })
           .catch(e => console.log(e));
```

Comment: Following answer might solve the issue: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57952971/8087054

Answer (score 2):

I was facing this issue because I had Chrome also running the same app and using the webcam. So basically the webcam was already in use and I was trying to access it via Firefox too.

Answer (score 0):

Are you really sure that you need adapter? In my experience it makes more problems than it solves.

Can you try to use constraints?

Example (I removed some things, but it works like a charm here):

```
 constraints = {
    width: 1280,
    height: 720,
    frameRate: 10, //mobile
    facingMode: {
        exact: "environment"
    } //mobile
}



navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({
    audio: false,
    video: constraints
}).
then(handleSuccess).catch(handleError);


function handleSuccess(stream) {
    video.src = URL.createObjectURL(stream);
    video.play();
}

function handleError(error) {
    console.log('navigator.getUserMedia error: ', error);
}
```

Comment: Removing adapter leads to a broken image in google chrome and it doesn't change firefox. The constraints also don't work, the error stays the same.

Comment: @Benjamin hi, did you manage to get it working? I've exactly same issue when trying to use back camera on Android. Similar error with android chrome (NotReadableError / Could not start video source) but NI issues with iOS / Safari. 
Just to clarify: front camera works ok.
Back camera works ok ony if I don't have webrtc call established.
Thanks.

Comment: I also experience this issue with Firefox 79 on Windows 10 x86-64, without knowing what's causing it -- no frameworks, just pure vanilla JavaScript.